# about including QcontactObserver in my Qt project?

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

I want to run the example found here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/samplephonebook.html

But I have an error in this line:

```
QContactObserver* m_observer;
```

The error is:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QContactObserver' with no type
```

in the `contacteditor.h` file.

What's wrong ? What should I do for that to run?

Comment: Is that the only error you get on that file?

Comment: @Mat : they're 2 errors exactly but i think the second depends on the first ----------->..\EditContacts\/contacteditor.h:64: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QContactObserver' with no type
..\EditContacts\/contacteditor.h:64: error: expected ';' before '*' token

Comment: you sure have a `#include <QContactObserver>`, don't you? Be carefull not to include after declaration of namespaces.

Comment: @mbx : when i include it .. I have an error "no such file or directory" :S

Comment: @MarwaShams Probably you don't have the needed file(s) so (re)install the mobility related SDK parts. (or it's just not known to the build system like missing path variable, missing cmake require package)

Comment: @mbx : I installed the latest SDK beta 1.1

Comment: @MarwaShams have you tried to `find` the file(or used its windows equivalent)?

Comment: If you don't find it, you may have missed to install the [QtMobility Addon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html).

Answer (score 1):

*This question may well have already been solved for the original OP, but for the sake of other users stumbling onto it:*

`QContactObserver` is part of [Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/index.html). Although Qt Mobility is included with the QtSDK, it must be [unpacked and built](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html) on the development system to ensure that it is configured properly to be used in a project on that system.

In addition, the *.pro* file [requires additions](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/quickstart.html) to prompt it to include the required Qt Mobility headers. For example, `QContactObserver` is part of the **QtContacts** module, so the *.pro* file would require the follwing additional lines:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += contacts
```

The error mentioned in the comments above:

> **MBX:** you sure have a `#include <QContactObserver>`, don't you?
>
> **Marwa Shams:** when i include it .. I have an error "no such file or directory"

occurs because Qt does not know where to look for the `<QContactObserver>` headers. Following the steps above will remedy the problem.